# Any way to identify the data type being used (2G/3G) in Android?

Tags: android

I need to stop the Android app from syncing data to the server when it is using 2G network connection and allow it when it is using 3G/4G or WiFi connection, the data/WiFi identification is easy but how can I know if the phone is currently using 2G mode or 3G/4G mode?

Using [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) can identify the SIM mode but not the actual data carrier being used in real-time, since Android assigns `E` icon for 2G and `H`,`H+`for 3G then there must be a way to identify this. Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my answer and gave you two ways of doing what you want, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.

On [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) you have some constants like [`TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE) to check that. Use those constants along with the methods `getType()` and `getSubtype()` from [`NetworkInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html).

**EDIT:** I was being stupid. You can simply call [`NetworkInfo.getSubtypeName`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getSubtypeName()) and you're good to go.

```
NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
Log.d("tag","Network type: " + info.getSubtypeName());
```

Or you could also try the other solution.

---

**OLD SOLUTION**

Try something like:

```
NetworkInfo info = Connectivity.getNetworkInfo(context);
getConnectionType(info.getType(),info.getSubtype());
```

And call this function:

```
private String getConnectionType(int type, int subType) {
if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
        return "WiFi";
    }
    else if(type==ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE){
        switch(subType){
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_1xRTT:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA:
            return "1G"; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS:
            return "2G"; // ~ 50-100 kbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_HSUPA:
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS:
            return "3G"; // ~ 2-14 Mbps
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE: // API level 11
            return "4G"; // ~ 10+ Mbps
        // Unknown
        case TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN:
        default:
            return "Not defined";
        }
    }
    else{
        return "Not defined";
    }
}
```

Of course, the method above is just a suggestion to show how it works, you can change it for your own purposes, and make it more complete, change the `return` type, etc.